# PHP MYSQL INT 0 on mysqliquery

Tags: php, mysql

im new student of php and mysql. I'm doing a voluntary little game for class. But I can not understand why when doing mysqli query it returns an int 0 when the database has 500 assigned. The game consists of a user who bets a certain amount of coins of his account, then a dice decides whether you win or not, taking 1,2,3 you lose, 4,5,6 you win. I post here the error or whatever this is.

```
include('conexion.php');

include('session.php');

$usuario=$_SESSION["username"];
$apuesta =$_POST["apuesta"];
$coins= "SELECT coins FROM `users` WHERE `usuario` = \"$usuario\"";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $coins)){
    echo "<br>";
    echo "hola";
    echo "<br>";
    var_dump($coins);
    echo "<br>";
    $coins2 = (int)$coins;
    var_dump($coins2);
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<br>";
    var_dump($coins2);
    echo "<br>";
    if ($apuesta>=$coins2) {
        echo "No tienes suficiente saldo";
        echo "<br>";
    }else {
        $dado = rand(1,6);
        if ($dado >3) {
            $apuesta = $coins2 + $apuesta;
            $cambiocartera = "UPDATE `users` SET `coins` = $apuesta WHERE `users`.`usuario` = '$usuario'";
            echo "<br>";
            echo "<h1>Ganaste = $dado";
            header( "refresh:3;url=dashboard.php");
        }
        elseif ($dado<4) {
            $apuesta = $coins2-$apuesta;
            $cambiocartera = "UPDATE `users` SET `coins` = $apuesta WHERE `users`.`usuario` = '$usuario'";
            echo "<br>";
            echo "<h1>Perdiste = $dado</h1>";
            header( "refresh:3;url=dashboard.php" );
        }
    }
}else {
    echo"error";
}
```

[image: mysql database of users and coins]

My browser message about the int on 0 that i dont understand why.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$coins` is the string containing the query, it's not the column you're retrieving from the table. When you convert a string to a number, it returns `0` if there's nothing numeric at the beginning.

You need to assign the result of `mysqli_query()` to a variable, then call a fetch function on that.

```
if ($result = mysqli_query($conn, $coins)) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $num_coins = $row['coins'];
    var_dump($num_coins);
```